Permissions not allowed being displayed in android.settings when using jadx
First, I’d like to mention that I’m relatively new to Android development, with just over 6 months of experience. If this question seems overly basic or naive, I sincerely apologize in advance.
I’m currently working on a payment app for a client. Due to the nature of its use, the client has requested extremely strong security measures. I’ve managed to meet all their requirements except for one.
The client sent me back an email saying that it still lacks removing a few more permissions. He ran a decompilar called jadx and said that i need to remove all of folowiwing permissions:

Even thought i DID add node remove to these permissions, it keeps showing up when i compile it and run the jadx tool on the apk:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" tools:node="remove"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" tools:node="remove"/>

Can any of you guys just gime a gimpse on how to remove these and why they are not being removed with the node remove tool inside the AndroidManifest.xml

Any library (and library used by that library) can add permissions and other content ho Android manifest.xml. if you really care about security you should know all the libraries your project uses. However a permission like MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE added by a library shows that you doesn't seem to care much about the libraries you use as this is a permission that no serious library would request as usually it end up that Google Play store rejects the app.

First, I’d like to say that I truly appreciate your comment. I’m still a beginner in Android development, so I’m not entirely sure how to verify all the permissions required by a dependency. Thank you for pointing that out!
